# There are $5$ white,$4$ yellow,$3$ green,$2$blue and $1$ red ball.

Tags: combinatorics

There are $5$ white,$4$ yellow,$3$ green,$2$blue and $1$ red ball.The balls are all identical except for colour. These are to be arranged in a line in $5$ places.Find the number of distinct arrangements.

---

There are following ways to arrange them in $4$ places
$(1)$ all different
$(2)$a pair and $3$ different
$(3)$two pair of different colours and $1$ different colour
$(4)$ a pair and a triad of different colours
$(5)$a triad of one colour and two singles of different colours
$(6)$a quad of one colour and a single of another colour
$(7)$ all five balls of same colour
Further i am stuck.The answer given in the book is $2111.$

Comment: What do yo mean "arranged in a line in 5 places"?

Comment: It means $5$ balls in a line.

Comment: I think you are right - you just have to slog away and calculate each of (1)-(7). Most are fairly easy, but care is needed.

Comment: Please add your calculations for the cases and indicate where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"$(1)$ all different
$(2)$a pair and $3$ different
$(3)$two pair of different colours and $1$ different colour
$(4)$ a pair and a triad of different colours
$(5)$a triad of one colour and two singles of different colours
$(6)$a quad of one colour and a single of another colour
$(7)$ all five balls of same colour
Further i am stuck.The answer given in the book is $2111.$"

$1.$ $5! = 120$

$2.$ $C(4,1)C(4,3)5!/2! = 960 $

$3.$ $C(4,2)C(3,1)5!/(2!2!) = 540 $

$4.$ $C(3,1)C(3,1)5!/(2!3!) = 90 $

$5.$ $C(3,1)C(4,2)5!/3! = 360 $

$6.$ $C(2,1)C(4,1)5!/4! = 40 $

$7.$ $1$

It sums to $2111$.