# A nice problem: How many ways can we connect $3$ yellow balls, $2$ blue and $1$ green, according to the rule?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinations

How many ways can we connect $3$ yellow balls, $2$ blue and $1$ green, according to the following rule?

- Yellow Balls ("A" elements) make up to 1 link
- Blue Balls ("B" elements) make up to 2 links
- Green Balls ("C" elements) make up to 3 links

Consider also:

- The balls may or may not connect;
- The balls are spread out in space, so do not consider fixed positions (what matters are the connections and not the positions)!
- Rotations and reflections of connections between the same elements are considered the same!

The problem is illustrated in the figure below:
[image]

To better understand the question, follow a simpler example in the figure below:
[image]

Remembering that:
[image]

Is it a combination problem? Is there a formula or analytical method to solve this type of problem? Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this will help
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1730271/there-are-5-white-4-yellow-3-green-2blue-and-1-red-ball